# Initializer Element is not a constant->Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting "Initializer Element is not a constant" error for the following declaration.

```
struct EBD_HEADER
{
    char   x;              
    int Key;     
    char Number;   
    int ID;       
    int Version;   
}EBD_HEAD;

struct EBD_TRAILER
{
    int Crc_0;            
    int Crc_1;           
    int  Etx;              
}EBD_TRAIL;

static const int EBD_HEADER_SIZE  = sizeof(EBD_HEAD);

static const int EBD_TRAILER_SIZE = sizeof(EBD_TRAIL);

static const int RMH_ENCODED_MSG_OVERHEAD = EBD_HEADER_SIZE + 
EBD_TRAILER_SIZE; //**error:Intializer Element is not a constant**
```

Comment: static const int RMH_ENCODED_MSG_OVERHEAD = sizeof(EBD_HEAD) + sizeof(EBD_TRAIL); This compile fine. Don't know why.

Comment: @taskinoor:Yeah i did as you told and it works.But i have 7 to 8 such declarations and so i replaced with macro as epatel asked me to do

Comment: @ron, yes the answer of epatel is better. Mine is not even an answer. I am just curious what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use macros instead.

```
#define EBD_HEADER_SIZE sizeof(EBD_HEAD)
#define EBD_TRAILER_SIZE sizeof(EBD_TRAIL)
#define RMH_ENCODED_MSG_OVERHEAD (EBD_HEADER_SIZE + EBD_TRAILER_SIZE)
```

Feels scary? Read [this](http://www.idinews.com/macroPhobe.html) and remember this is C (which Objective-C is based on) and not C++

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me to understand about macros.

Answer (score 2):

`static const int` in C declares a *variable* of type `int` whose value can be assumed (when optimising) not to change. It doesn’t declare a constant, unlike in C++.

If you want integer constants in plain C, you can either use macros as the previous answer suggests, or use an `enum` instead.  Note that you are allowed to use anonymous `enum`s; e.g.

```
enum {
  EBD_HEADER_SIZE = sizeof (EBD_HEAD),
  EBD_TRAILER_SIZE = sizeof (EBD_TRAIL),
  RMH_ENCODED_MSG_OVERHEAD = sizeof (EBD_HEAD) + sizeof (EBD_TRAIL)
};
```

Note that using `enum` for this purpose is not without its problems; you can only declare constants of integral type this way, and if you decide to use a named `enum` (either via a tag or via `typedef`), it’s worth noting that some compilers will choose different sizes or alignments for your type according to the number and values of its member constants.

Obviously, using `#define` also has a few drawbacks, not least the well-known problems of accidental multiple evaluation of side-effects and operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks alaster for explaining me clearly about enums and macros.